# Remote Inter-device Communication with GameKit

Tags: ios, gamekit

I am developing a pair of apps for my company.  One will be used by one of our sales reps, and the other will be distributed to our clients.  The sales app is distributed through Enterprise, and the client app will be distributed through the App Store.

At some point, I need these two apps to communicate with each other (running on separate devices) remotely.  I can at best guarantee that the two users will be connected to the internet via wi-fi.

I have done some preliminary research but failed to find the answers to these particular questions:

1. <strike>Can GameKit form a connection over the internet?

   All of the documentation refers to local Wi-Fi connections, which seems to mean two users connected to the same Wi-Fi network.</strike>
2. <strike>Can GameKit form a connection between two apps with different bundle IDs?

   Again, looked through the docs and failed to find anything specifying the two users must be running the same exact app, different versions are allowed, but that seems to imply they must have the same bundle ID.</strike>
3. If I use GameKit matchmaking to pair my two users, will that make my app show up in Game Center?
4. Am I breaking some terms of use by allowing communication between my Enterprise app, and my  App Store app?

EDIT:I was able to find a note in the GameKit programming guilde noting that apps with different bundle IDs can connect through Game Kit

EDIT2: Found this quote in the Game Kit Programming Guide seemingly indicating that location and network type is not an issue for connectivity:

> Where necessary, Game Kit routes network data through Game Center’s servers so that all of the match’s participants are connected to each other, regardless of where they are or what kind of network they are on.